# Python wondering about user input

Tags: python, python-2.7

Letss say the user wants to input 100 things; but I don't want to make my script have 100, `x = raw_input('')`, is there away to do this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response for techniques to ensure that the user input is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list and a `while` loop.

```
data=[]

for x in xrange(100):
    data.append(raw_input("Your data: "))
```

If you don't need to store the data that was entered, get rid of the list and process this data right in the loop.

Comment: Note: `data = [raw_input("Your data: ") for _ in xrange(100)]`.